# Java Lambdas and Streams: pass streams around

Tags: java, lambda, guava, java-stream, lazy-evaluation

I have a fairly dumb question. We all know that stream can have a number of intermediate operations but the real computation is done only when we call some terminal operation. Is it common to pass streams around without calling terminal operation for a long time?

Let me explain what I mean. Consider the following example with Iterator/Iterable

1. Read file with buffered reader in lines, return Iterator with
   next() overrided to call `reader.readLine()`
2. In the upper class use guava's Iterators.transform to say lowercase
   everything.
3. In the upper class wrap with another Iterator which may be split's
   the line from upstream iterator by coma and returning tuples of
   words in the line
4. In the final class consume the iterator by iterating over it and
   writing to some OutputStream.

With all that I have completely lazy computation done from the start till the end. No intermediate collections are used, etc.

If I wanted to do the same with streams I guess I should pass around the Stream object itself. Is it very common to do so? Can you share some links with me?

Comment: This is not particularly standard.  Almost all stream operations should be done in a single chain.  If you want each class to provide methods that do things like split lines by commas, and then have one other class that does a whole stream operation by composing the operations from each class, that's more typical.

Comment: It's a good practice to return a Stream from the method. It's not nice to accept Stream as a parameter.

Comment: @TagirValeev thanks, nice answer. Guava's transformers are actually taking Iterables as params to make a composition, is doing so considered bad practice for streams, why? I can nest the classes and each one will delegate to the downstream to get the stream and add something on top, i.e. return splitter.getStream() { return lineReader.getStream().flatMap(Stream.of(Splitter::split)); }. But in general what if classes may be composed differently to contribute to the stream? I don't see any way to achieve that without passing streams as parameters, i.e. splitter.apply(lineReader.getStream()).

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk. the main difference is that Stream is always once-off while iterable could be reused. If you accept a Stream, you will not be able to traverse it twice (unless you collect it to list/array). So you will be limited in method implementation.

Comment: @TagirValeev Agree on Iterables, but Iterators can be exhausted the same way as streams, Guava provides the same kind of stuff there: concat, filter, transform, etc. I don't see much of a difference between Stream and Iterator here..